# How to move out of a python string with C-M-u

Tags: key-bindings, python, navigation

I'm used to using `backward-up-list` to go to the front of a string in most every programming mode, but for some reason it doesn't work in python-mode. python-mode rebinds <kbd>C-M-u</kbd> to its own `python-nav-backward-up-list` which doesn't work within strings

I would rebind the keybinding myself, but the default command doesn't work in other, more python specific situations so I'm kind of stuck between a rock and a hard place

Answer (score 0):

`python-nav-backward-up-list` excludes both strings and comments.

```
(defun my/python-backward-up-list (&optional arg)
  "Move backward out of one level of parentheses, strings, or blocks.
With ARG, do this that many times.
A negative argument means move forward but still to a less deep spot."
  (interactive "^p")
  (let ((context (python-syntax-context-type)))
    (if (memq context '(string comment))
        (backward-up-list arg t nil)
      (python-nav-backward-up-list arg))))
```